# Linq query to iterate group and filter only selected type

Tags: c#, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyhPq.png)

I have a collection of Group which have warning and Categories. I have attached the screen shot on how the Groups have been structured.

So based on the type I want to Filter the group like in the above case I want only type which has "Contra-indication" value alone.

```
private void UpdateFromWarnings(ReadOnlyCollection<Group> groups)
        {
            Rows.Clear();

            if (groups != null && groups.Any())
            {
                IsNoWarningsFoundTextVisible = false;
               
// I thought about filtering the group via the below linq query


                //var data = groups[0].Warnings[0].select(x => x.type == "Contra-Indication")

                //ReadOnlyCollection<Group> gp =  

                Rows.AddRange(
                    _rowFactory.Create(groups).ToArray());
            }
            else
                IsNoWarningsFoundTextVisible = true;
        }
```

But I'm not sure whether the approach is correct. I am new to Linq. Let me know how to approach the problem.

Comment: Do you want to have Group who contain at least one Warning with a specific type?
Or do you only want Warning with a specific type?

Comment: @Arcord I want warning with a specific type alone.

Comment: Check my answer, the second option should be what you want. You'll end up with a list a warning with the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

In that way you will keep all groups containing at least one warning with the type you want:

```
groups.Where(g => g.Warnings.Any(w => w.Type == "MyType"))
```

In that way you will keep all warnings containing of the type you want:

```
groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings).Where(w => w.Type == "MyType")
```

Edit:
With this you will get all groups containing at least one warning with the specified type + the list of warning having the specified type.

```
var groupsAndWarning =  groups
.Where(g => g.Warnings.Any(w => w.Type == "MyType")
.Select(g => new { Group = g, Warnings = g.Where(w => w.Type == "MyType"))
```

That way "groupsAndWarning" will be a list, each item will have a "Group" property (only group with warning having the specific type) and the "Warnings" property will only contains the Warning of the specific type and tied to this group.

Comment: Thanks for helping with ur answer. I just need one clarification like how to add category with warning, I want both to be listed. Your solution provides only warnings for the given type. can you guide on how to show both category and warning for the given type

Comment: I edit my answer, you can combine both query to get and the groups and the warning.